# Cannot change TextBox Text to contain two decimal places

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I have a TextBox, on LostFocus I run a function that converts the value to a decimal with two zeros at the end. (eg. 192 becomes 192,00).

The TextBox in xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="AmountGross"  
         Text="{Binding AmountGross, StringFormat='0.00',
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
         ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
         ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, 
         NotifyOnValidationError=true}" 
         GotKeyboardFocus="TextBoxGotKeyboardFocusHandler"
         TextChanged="TextBoxTextChangedHandler"
         PreviewKeyUp="DEFixedButtonPreviewKeyUpHandler" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" LostFocus="TextBoxLostFocus" >
 </TextBox>
```

And the TextBoxLostFocus code:

```
if (cell.Text != "")
{
    decimal value = -1;
    if (decimal.TryParse(cell.Text, out value))
    {
        string a = string.Format("{0:N}", Convert.ToDecimal(value)); //THIS LINE CONVERTS IT TO 192,00
        cell.Text = a.ToString().Replace(".", ""); //HERE THE CELL.TEXT IS 192
    }
}
```

The conversion (192 to 192,00) works great but when I assign the Text to the TextBox, it changes into integer (192).

**Edit:**
The a variable is correct (55,00).
When it got assigned to cell.Text then it removes the comma separator and it becomes: (5500).
[var A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wqO4.jpg)
[cell.Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNnXh.jpg)

Why is this happening and how can I avoid that?

Comment: But you are explicitly removing the decimal separator using the `Replace` method?!

Comment: This is not the problem. Even with Replace the Text should be 19200. But Convert.ToDecimal uses comma (",") and not dot (".").

Comment: I see. You decimal separator is the comma and not the dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just realized that your localized decimal separator is the comma.

The trailing zeros are truncated by default:

```
(19200,00).ToString() // Output: 19200
```

You can use [the "." custom specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-1):

```
(19200,00).ToString("0.00") // Output: 19200,00
```

Or [the Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-numeric-n-format-specifier) (which will also add a group separator):

```
(19200,00).ToString("N2") // Output: 19.200,00
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably gets the data type from the "AmountGross" property so if it's int the TextBox get this type as default data type, try change the property type to decimal.

Comment: It is decimal: 
        private decimal? _amountGross;
        public decimal? AmountGross
        {
            get { return _amountGross; }
            set
            {
                if (Setter(ref _amountGross, value, nameof(AmountGross)))
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }